# Formulate a problem with Bayes Theorem: the sequence of A and B

Tags: bayesian

When I read up the example for Bayes Theorem I come across the following in [link](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/probability-main-index/bayes-theorem-problems/), which confuses me.

> Bayes’ Theorem Example #1 You might be interested in finding out a
> patient’s probability of having liver disease if they are an
> alcoholic. “Being an alcoholic” is the test (kind of like a litmus
> test) for liver disease.
>
> A could mean the event “Patient has liver disease.” Past data tells
> you that 10% of patients entering your clinic have liver disease. P(A)
> = 0.10. B could mean the litmus test that “Patient is an alcoholic.” Five percent of the clinic’s patients are alcoholics. P(B) = 0.05. You
> might also know that among those patients diagnosed with liver
> disease, 7% are alcoholics. This is your B|A: the probability that a
> patient is alcoholic, given that they have liver disease, is 7%.
> Bayes’ theorem tells you: P(A|B) = (0.07 * 0.1)/0.05 = 0.14 In other
> words, if the patient is an alcoholic, their chances of having liver
> disease is 0.14 (14%). This is a large increase from the 10% suggested
> by past data. But it’s still unlikely that any particular patient has
> liver disease.

I am wondering why the target probability is not P(liver disease|alcoholic), but is P(alcoholic|liver disease), since it is asking 'finding out a patient’s probability of having liver disease if they are an alcoholic'. I'm wondering if I have some misconception about Bayes Theorem or the website itself is not precise enough. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your intuition is right, but I also think the site is correct. I think it's easy to get turned around with Bayes' rule, so my guess is your confusion is from learning to juggle the new notation. We are targeting $P(\text{liver}\hspace{1mm}\text{disease}|\text{alcoholic})$ like you said.

We can map what the book says:

$A$: patient has liver disease. $P(A) = 0.1$.

$B$: patient is an alcoholic. $P(B) = 0.05$.

$B|A$: patient is an alcoholic *given* they have liver disease. $P(B|A) = 0.07$.

So the target is $P(A|B)$: the probability that the patient has liver disease *given* they are an alcoholic. So we apply Bayes' theorem to find

$P(\text{liver}\hspace{1mm}\text{disease}|\text{alcoholic})=P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)} = \frac{(0.07)(0.1)}{0.05} = 0.14$

So the target probability is what you thought it was.